# Is Greyscale function of Wicked_PDF functional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

In my project I am trying to print a PDF in Greyscale with a couple of images and text from HTML using the wicked_PDF. The Gem provides a function for the same, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
    render :pdf => "MyObject",
            :wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
            :template => '/widgets/pdf/show_myObject.erb',
            :page_size => 'A4',
            :header => { :html => { :template => "/widgets/pdf/myObject_header.erb" }},
            :footer => { :html => { :template => "/widgets/pdf/myObject_footer.erb" }, :line => true },
            :margin => { :top => 0, :left => 3, :right => 3 },
            :greyscale => true
```

I am passing the images as background. But it renders in color. Am I missing something? Why is wicked_PDF gem unable to process greyscale function as expected?

Their [documentation](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md) did not have any help regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the wkhtmltopdf `--grayscale` option was incorrectly coded in wicked_pdf as `--greyscale`

(swap the 'e' for an 'a').

I've pushed a fix, and cut a new version of the gem (0.7.9) for this. Thanks for pointing it out!

```
:grayscale => true
```

Now works as intended.